# Azure -Destination Port Ranges

Tags: azure

While trying to run the following command from cloudshell:

```
DPortRange=*
az network nsg rule create -g $ResourceGroup --nsg-name $NSG -n $RULENAME --priority 100 
--destination-address-prefixes $Destination --destination-port-ranges $DPortRange --direction 
inbound --access Allow --protocol TCP
```

it returns an error message that shell cannot interpet * , I tried to escape this special characther but the same error occurs. Only the following seems to work after omitting apparently the variable and define explicitly the parameter :

```
--destination-port-ranges '*'
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

**According To this [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-create), if you want to use wild card(*) for destination Port range parameter while creating a nsg rule it should be passed in single quotes only.**

> [image]

**I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-create) and [Github-doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic-cli.md):**

```
   az network nsg rule create \  
    --resource-group resourcegrp-name \  
    --nsg-name windowsserver2019-nsg \  
    --name allowinboundall \  
    --access Allow \  
    --protocol Tcp \  
    --direction Inbound \  
    --priority 100 \  
    --source-address-prefix "*" \  
    --source-port-range "*" \  
    --destination-port-range "*"
```

[image]

**Output:
Once ran the above commands rule created successfully as below:**

[image]